# Recursion error caused in django when trying to read from files

Tags: python, django, pandas, user-interface

I am working on a project for displaying my university's energy data but when I am trying to read from my university's excel sheets that store data, I am getting the following error:

```
RecursionError at /multiplication/
maximum recursion depth exceeded
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/multiplication/
```

Here is my views.py class without pandas:

```
from django.shortcuts import render,get_object_or_404
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from django import forms
#import pandas as pd
# Create your views here.

# def startPage(request):
#     return render(request, 'multiplication/detail.html')

template_name1 = 'multiplication/detail.html'

class myForm(forms.Form):
     quantity1 = forms.IntegerField(required=False)
     quantity2 = forms.IntegerField(required=False)
#main method

def multiply_two_integers(x,y):
     return x*y

def read_excel(ExcelFileName):
     File = read_excel(ExcelFileName)
     return File

def my_view(request):
     read_excel("AH1_Hahn_26032017_29032017.xl.xlsx")
```

If I try to import pandas as pd, then I get a different type of error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/NikolasPapastavrou/firstProject/multiplication/views.py", 
line 14, in <module>
import pandas as pd
File "/Users/NikolasPapastavrou/firstProject/pandas/__init__.py", line 
19, in <module>
"Missing required dependencies {0}".format(missing_dependencies))
ImportError: Missing required dependencies ['numpy']
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to use pandas you need to install numpy.

From numpy docs:

In most use cases the best way to install NumPy on your system is by using a pre-built package for your operating system.

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/install.html

I recommend using the Anaconda package. If you are serious about numeric analysis it is the go to option. Especially if its one of your firsts projects. In the following link you can download Anaconda.

https://www.anaconda.com/download/#linux

If you prefer not to use pandas. When I had the need to import data from Excel files. I have always had a better experience transforming the spreadsheets to csv first. Then read the data row by row. If you are a Linux user there are great terminal commands available to programatically perform the task.